# Linking database with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In Microsoft SQL Server Menagment Studio I created database Bookstore with server name .\SQLEXPRESS. In MVC inweb.config i wrote:

```
<add name="DBCS" connectionString="server=.\SQLEXPRESS; database=Bookstore; integrated security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

On my computer it is working but when I try to run on another it's not working. I copied project file, Bookstore.mdf file and Bookstore.ldf file.
 I think that its not connected to my database. Do I need to change something in my code and what to do?

Comment: `.\SQLEXPRESS` means the *locally installed* instance of the database server. If your database doesn't exist on another machine, it won't work. Look for LocalDB for integrated deployment (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx).

Comment: I don't get it. What I need to do, please help?

Comment: You should attach the file Bookstore.mdf file to SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're trying to run your application with a local database / `LocalDB`,change `connectionString` to something like this (assuming database files are in `AppData` folder):

```
<add name="DBCS" 
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Bookstore.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
/>
```

If your database must exists on a different machine,you have to replace the `.` in `.\sqlexpress` with the IP or url of your server,I'm assuming database instance name on your server is named `sqlexpress`